# remount boot partition as readonly

Tags: rhel, mount, boot, snapshot

I am working on a snapshot driver for the block devices on RHEL 6 and RHEL7 and there is some problem during snapshot specific to boot on RHEL 7, which i am suspecting due to COW related. When I checked, it was mounted as RW mode. I have few questions

1. Why boot is mounted as RW?
2. How can i remount boot as read-only?

I tried below command but it didn't work for me

> mount -f -o remount,ro /boot

The problem is specific to RHEL 7 boot partition (/dev/sda1 in my case) only.

Comment: mount worked for me. I was able to mount it in read-only mode by simply removing -f from above command. But still I don't understand why we need rw mode for boot partition.